# PHP 5.6 to upgrade PHP 7 causes failed opening required include_path='.:/usr/local/php70/pear

Tags: php, wordpress

We have developed a WordPress/WooCommerce website using PHP 5.6 and we would like to upgrade to PHP7. The website works perfectly on 5.6 but running it on PHP7 would increase the speed of the website.

The change to PHP7 causes the following 500 error:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required ''
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php70/pear') in
>   /home/servername/public_html/customer/customername/wp-content/themes/flux/framework/qode-framework.php
>   on line 4

We did a quick test with a copy of the site on another PHP7 server from another hosting and there PHP7 works fine. So it should be a server setting, but I can't figure it out.

If someone could help me understand the problem, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: See In `qode-framework.php` line no 4, included file path wrong. Replace with correct file path inside function `require_once()`.

Comment: @AHJeebon Thanks for your feedback. in `qode-framework.php` on line 4 it states `require_once("lib/qode.framework.php");`  The file is there. Could it be something goes wrong with the relative pathname? Somewhere on stackoverflow I read about a similar error and it had something to do with a wrong root. Can I include a absolute pathname?

Comment: Use relative path:  `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/**here write your relative path, if back directory then use (../)**');`

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I implemented your suggestion but the error remains similar. Failed opening required went from ' ' to '%':  `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '%' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php70/pear') in /home/servername/public_html/customer/customername/wp-content/themes/flux/framework/qode-framework.php on line 4`

Comment: I have similar problem whit my host, my app works file with php 5.6, but when I switching to php 7, 7.2, 7.4 I will get 'include_path='.:/usr/local/php70/pear
' error with each version of php, so I think the problem is php version, I still looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/home/servername/public_html/customer/customername/wp-content/themes/flux/framework/qode-framework.php` file on line 4 and do like following code for example:

```
require_once(realpath(__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'));
```

or

```
require_once(realpath(__DIR__.'/../your-file-path'));
```

or

```
require_once(realpath(__DIR__.'/your-file-path'));
```

make sure to use [realpath(), this command will convert a relative path to an absolute one](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths)